# Unity Shop System How to Solve AddListener Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a shop system in unity but i have a problem about AddListener. I couldn't understood the addlistener code. Here is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
public class SkinChangeButton : MonoBehaviour{
private SkinSpawner skinSpawner;

   [System.Obsolete]



void MarketiCagir()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < skinSpawner.items.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject cogalanslot = Instantiate(skinSpawner.Slot, transform);
        cogalanslot.transform.FindChild("Character_Image").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = skinSpawner.items[i].Resim;
        cogalanslot.transform.Find("Purchase_Button").transform.Find("Price_Text").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = skinSpawner.items[i].Fiyat.ToString();
        cogalanslot.transform.Find("Character_FunInfo").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = skinSpawner.items[i].FunInfo.ToString();
        bool gecicibool = skinSpawner.items[i].Alinmadurum;
        int gecici = i;
        cogalanslot.transform.Find("Purchase_Button").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Buy(gecici, cogalanslot, gecicibool));
        cogalanslot.transform.Find("Purchase_Button").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => SkinChangingReal(gecici, cogalanslot, gecicibool));




    }
}
public void SkinChange()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < skinSpawner.items.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject cogalanslot = Instantiate(skinSpawner.Slot, transform);

        bool gecicibool = skinSpawner.items[i].Alinmadurum;
        int gecici = i;
        SkinChangingReal(gecici);



    }
}
public void Buy(int id, GameObject obje, bool AlinmaDurum)
{
    skinSpawner.Para = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("StarCoin", 0);
    if (skinSpawner.Para >= skinSpawner.items[id].Fiyat)
    {


        obje.transform.Find("Purchase_Button").gameObject.SetActive(false);
        skinSpawner.Para -= skinSpawner.items[id].Fiyat;

        skinSpawner.items[id].Alinmadurum = true;


    }

}
public void SkinChangingReal(int id)
{
   

    if (skinSpawner.items[id].Alinmadurum)
    {
        skinSpawner.Player.sprite = skinSpawner.items[id].Resim;

    }

}
```

}

[image]

I'm trying to make a shop using scroll rect shouldn't i use the addlistener script?Is there another way to solve this problem? How can i solve this problem? Thank you :)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Comment: And we'll your method only takes one single argument ... did you maybe rather want to call `Buy` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your `SkinChangingReal(int id)` method takes in a single argument, but you are calling it with 3 arguments here:

```
cogalanslot.transform.Find("Purchase_Button").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => SkinChangingReal(gecici, cogalanslot, gecicibool));
```